# Yum can find a package, but can not install it

Tags: rhel, yum

How is it possible?

```
[root@server1 ~]# yum search diy
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
======================================= N/S Matched: diy =======================================
openshift-origin-cartridge-diy-0.1.noarch : Provides diy support

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
[root@server1 ~]# yum install openshift-origin-cartridge-diy
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
No package openshift-origin-cartridge-diy available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@server1 ~]#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
yum install openshift-origin-cartridge-diy-0.1
```

Comment: it works, but WHY?

Comment: Because the package name is: openshift-origin-cartridge-diy-0.1 not openshift-origin-cartridge-diy

Comment: What Sepahrad said!